# Java GUI with JFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Today I started learning Java GUI and tried to create a simple window on my Ubuntu. I am using jre7 for now.
I wrote code exactly from tutorial because from experience there are stuff that doesn't work even if it's correctly typed onto my screen. So, now I used thenewboston's first tutorial with Java GUI. Typed all syntax correctly, classes seems fine, no errors.
He got window that was expected - mine only got blank window with no title and no text.

Screenshot with that [image]
<sub>(source: [scaleengine.net](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/07ad762a0450ac18e60bc0083a5018a6.png))</sub>

Code in JFrames.java file:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // importē plūstošo skatu / default layout
import javax.swing.JFrame; // dod iespēju piekļūt pamata logu struktūrai
import javax.swing.JLabel; // ļauj rakstīt tekstu logos

public class JFrames extends JFrame {

    private JLabel item1;
    
    public JFrames() {
        super("The Title Of The Program"); // parāda title bar ar tekstu
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        item1 = new JLabel("This is sentence with something");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is tooltip on hover");
        add(item1); // pievieno logam šo lietiņu
    }
}
```

Please, ignore latvian comments, that's just for my reference.
So I want to know - why my window appears blank?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) as opposed to one code snippet and a screenshot of your IDE.

Answer (score 5):

In the screenshot, your code says:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

That should be `JFrames` with an `s`.

```
JFrames frame = new JFrames();
```